# Android JSON HttpClient to send data to PHP server with HttpResponse

Tags: php, android, json, httpclient, httpresponse

I am currently trying to send some data from and Android application to a php server (both are controlled by me).

There is alot of data collected on a form in the app, this is written to the database. This all works.

In my main code, firstly I create a JSONObject (I have cut it down here for this example):

```
JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
j.put("engineer", "me");
j.put("date", "today");
j.put("fuel", "full");
j.put("car", "mine");
j.put("distance", "miles");
```

Next I pass the object over for sending, and receive the response:

```
String url = "http://www.server.com/thisfile.php";
HttpResponse re = HTTPPoster.doPost(url, j);
String temp = EntityUtils.toString(re.getEntity());
if (temp.compareTo("SUCCESS")==0)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Sending complete!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The HTTPPoster class:

```
public static HttpResponse doPost(String url, JSONObject c) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException 
{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
    HttpEntity entity;
    StringEntity s = new StringEntity(c.toString());
    s.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
    entity = s;
    request.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response;
    response = httpclient.execute(request);
    return response;
}
```

This gets a response, but the server is returning a 403 - Forbidden response.

I have tried changing the doPost function a little (this is actually a little better, as I said I have alot to send, basically 3 of the same form with different data - so I create 3 JSONObjects, one for each form entry - the entries come from the DB instead of the static example I am using).

Firstly I changed the call over a bit:

```
String url = "http://www.myserver.com/ServiceMatalan.php";
Map<String, String> kvPairs = new HashMap<String, String>();
kvPairs.put("vehicle", j.toString());
// Normally I would pass two more JSONObjects.....
HttpResponse re = HTTPPoster.doPost(url, kvPairs);
String temp = EntityUtils.toString(re.getEntity());
if (temp.compareTo("SUCCESS")==0)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Sending complete!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Ok so the changes to the doPost function:

```
public static HttpResponse doPost(String url, Map<String, String> kvPairs) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException 
{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    if (kvPairs != null && kvPairs.isEmpty() == false) 
    {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(kvPairs.size());
        String k, v;
        Iterator<String> itKeys = kvPairs.keySet().iterator();
        while (itKeys.hasNext()) 
        {
            k = itKeys.next();
            v = kvPairs.get(k);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(k, v));
        }             
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    }
    HttpResponse response;
    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    return response;
}
```

Ok So this returns a response 200

```
int statusCode = re.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

However the data received on the server cannot be parsed to a JSON string. It is badly formatted I think (this is the first time I have used JSON):

If in the php file I do an echo on $_POST['vehicle'] I get the following:

```
{\"date\":\"today\",\"engineer\":\"me\"}
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong, or if there is a better way to achieve what I am trying to do? Hopefully the above makes sense!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to document your issue w/ the 403 response. Had the same thing for a week and your post finally has me moving in the right direction!

Comment: @Toran Billups not a problem, I'm glad it has helped you!!

Comment: Your variables post to your PHP script correctly. How would you pull each variable say "engineer" and "fuel" and insert them into a MySQL database for example. It looks like all you can do is just use the `$_POST['vehicle'];` variable. Would very much welcome a response to this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After lots of reading and searching I have found the problem to be with, I beleive magic_quotes_gpc being enabled on the server.

Thus, using:

```
json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['vehicle']));
```

In my example above removes the slashes and allows the JSON to be decoded properly.

Still not sure why sending a StringEntity causes a 403 error?

Comment: Could you possibly share your PHP file that contains `json_decode` because I think how my server is decoding the json data (wrongly) may be related to yours.

Comment: json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['vehicle']), true); will return php array, json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['vehicle'])); returns php stdclass obj, which is hard to use. +1 for correct answer, thx

Answer (score 4):

```
StringEntity s = new StringEntity(c.toString());
s.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
s.setContentType("application/json");
request.setEntity(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
(String url = "http://www.server.com/MainPage.php";)
```

to

```
(String url = "http://www.server.com/MainPage.php?";)
```

Question mark at the end is necessary when you're trying to send parameters to php script.

Comment: Thanks Sergey, but I am using a POST method to send the data, not passing parameters for GET from the PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code it works perfectly**

```html
*For HttpClient class* download jar file "httpclient-4.3.6.jar" and put in libs folder then
Compile:   dependencies {compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.6.jar')}

repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
```

*then call HttpClient class this AsyncTask Like this:*

private class YourTask extends AsyncTask {
        private String error_msg = "Server error!";

```
    private JSONObject response;



    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            JSONObject mJsonObject = new JSONObject();
            mJsonObject.put("user_id", "user name");
            mJsonObject.put("password", "123456");
            String URL=" Your Link"

            //Log.e("Send Obj:", mJsonObject.toString());

            response = HttpClient.SendHttpPost(URL, mJsonObject);
            boolean status = response != null && response.getInt("is_error") == 0; // response

            return status;
        } catch (JSONException | NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            mDialog.dismiss();
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean status) {
       // your code

    }
}
```