# How to upload multipart Image data in json request Android?

Tags: android

I have to upload image data in multipart post using json request so can anyone help me out here.

Here is my json string request to send server (**I am able to create JSON request in string but how to send that code is required**)

```
{
"Request": {
    "data": {
        "Key": "keydata",
        "info": {},
        "param": {
            "title": "Testingpostmultipartimageupload",
            "photo": **"IMAGE BYTE DATA"**,
            "photoFilename": "Test.png"
        }
    },
    "info": {}
}
```

}

So how can I post this data along with image byte data in JSON to webservice...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution based on this post: http://prativas.wordpress.com/2014/03/03/uploading-image-from-android-app-to-server-programmatically/:

And combined this with a multipart for the json data:

```
// the json values:
multiPartEntityBuilder.addPart("fieldname", new StringBody("value",ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON));

//the file:
File file = new File(filename);
FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);
multiPartEntityBuilder.addPart("FIle_Fieldname_depending_on_the_api", fileBody);
```

This uploads the file to a rest api (django restframework)