# OutOfMemoryException while sending an image to a webserver

Tags: android, base64, out-of-memory

So, to send an image to a web server i need to encode it to base64 and later decode on the server side.

This is what i am following.

But i get the OutOfMemoryException, at this line of code:

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

And the image size of **1mb**. So, any alternate way to do this?

I read this:

[Sending images using Http Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935946/sending-images-using-http-post#answers)

which recommends to use **MultipartEntity**. But where exactly can i find those libraries? because 1 of the links is broken.

**Code:**

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

try {
    File imageFile = new File(selectedImagePath);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile
            .getAbsolutePath());
    setImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    base64code = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Probably 1 way might be to reduce the quality. But if i set it to **20** or **30** and the image is already a low quality 1(taken from a low end device). I might get a bad quality image.

Doing something like check the size and reduce the quality depending on that. I don't think is a good idea.

Thank You

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416038/uploading-image-to-server-in-multipart-along-with-json-data-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upload images to server with MultipartEntity is one of the good option.

MultipartEntity libraries Downloads :

[apache-mime4j-0.6.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/apache-mime4j/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar.zip)

[httpmime-4.0.1.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/httpmime/httpmime-4.0.1.jar.zip)

Hope it helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: can i send **1-2 mb** files using MultipartEntity?