# Service Called from Android to C# not working

Tags: c#, android, web-services, post, web

What i am trying to do is send my image from Android over to my web service which is C#.
On the Android side i get no errors and no warning but have nothing to show for on the service, it never actually gets the image at all.

I'm still particularly new to Services this way, so any help would be greatly appreciated!!

My **Android** AsyncTask Looks like this:

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(File... file) {

            String imageDescriptionTemp = "Photo Temp Description.";
            String PostRequestUri = "https://demo.relocationmw.com/ws_docmgmt/Service1.svc";
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(PostRequestUri);
            FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(file[0]);
            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            entity.addPart("Image", bin1);
            post.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse response;
            try {
                response = client.execute(post);
                resEntity = response.getEntity();
                final String response_string = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
                if(resEntity != null){
                Log.i("RESPONSE", response_string); 
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

That there just calls to the service file on the server, sending the image and soon a description and everything.

here is my **C#** service code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Xml;


// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    #region vars
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();// Create the XML Declaration, and append it to XML document
    XmlElement root;

    #endregion

    public Stream GetImage(string path)
    {
        FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(@System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/attachments/test/") + "SrvTest.jpg");
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        return stream as Stream;
    }

    public XmlDocument UpImage(string path, Stream filecontents)
    {

        XmlDeclaration dec = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);

        doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;

        doc.AppendChild(dec);// Create the root element

        root = doc.CreateElement("UpImage");

        doc.AppendChild(root);


        XmlElement xml_item;
        xml_item = doc.CreateElement("Response");

        Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(filecontents);
        img.Save(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/attachments/test/") + "SrvTest.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        XmlElement item;
        item = doc.CreateElement("Success");
        item.InnerText = "Success";
        xml_item.AppendChild(item);

        return doc;

    }
}
```

This should accept my file and return an XML with SUCCESS for me to log.
again, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does your service work? Have you tested it with SoapUI? If not try it!

Comment: This is a REST service, would that tool work for this if so what is the WSDL? From my experiences with .Net i have looked over this code and it should work.

Comment: Have a read of http://www.soapui.org/REST-Testing/getting-started.html

Comment: try with soap, I heard some where that the rest is not good with c# (am not 100% sure abt it). I used soap with C# services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretend that your app is a common html form loaded into IE and send exactly what that form would send. That way you can test your server component with a simple test form.

To start, write a plain html form which submits an image to your service. Use an input element with the type attribute set to "file" and make sure to give the element a name, not just an id...

Once you can confirm that the html form posts successfully, you'll know the problem is in your android client code.

If the problem is in your android code, check the contents of the body. See that it isn't null, etc., then check to see that if has the Content-Type and Content-Disposition headers set properly.

If all of the above tests pass, check the boundary lines of your posts. I was nearly derailed by this issue twice a couple of years ago. (Invisible chars count.)

Here is a good example to look at: [Uploading image to server in Multipart along with JSON data in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416038/uploading-image-to-server-in-multipart-along-with-json-data-in-android)

Though it's got a different back end (Java), the http rules are the same.

-Brandon

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the service is operational, your problem probably lies with the fact that WCF adds a MIME header to the start of the stream.

This will mean that the received number of bytes seems longer than the sent number of bytes.

I've found a good example of what to do here:
http://www.ideatoappster.com/android-to-wcf-streaming-multi-part-binary-images/
Under the heading: **WTF?! My binary data contains more bytes when I read the Stream in WCF than when I send it from Android**