# How can i send JsonObject to server using Https Post request

Tags: android

How can i send my android application data (mobileNumber and message) which is in JSON format to server using HTTPS Post request. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HttpClient httpclient =new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost  httppost=new HttpPost(name of the website);
try{

    JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
    j.put("engineer", "me");

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(j));    
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    /*Checking response*/
    if(response!=null)
    {   
        responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

    }
    if(responseBody.equals("ok"))
    {

        //...do something

    }
} catch(ClientProtocolException e) {

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can also can take a look in here: [Android JSON HttpClient to send data to PHP server with HttpResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540786/android-json-httpclient-to-send-data-to-php-server-with-httpresponse)

Comment: Thank you. but,  it works based on HTTP?? or HTTPS?? Could you please tell me.

Comment: It works on Http for me, haven't tries with https.But is something very simple:).If it helps you don't forget to accept my answer by checking it from the left side.Thanks:)

Comment: How can i change the above code to work on HTTPS?? Could you please tell me.

Comment: sorry for the late reply but it seems that this works for both http and https!Did you try it and it is not working?

Comment: I haven't tried. But i want to know whether it works for "Https" also or not? can you please clarify me.

Comment: It wirks for both....just try it.It will take you 5 minutes.Not such a big deal....:)

Comment: @adrian...i am doing like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720923/sending-json-params-with-https-request......... can you please tell me where i am wrong because its not working well.

Comment: If u are using https and you server requires a certificate for authentication, you need to provide one:)