# How to test that output of my android code is in Json format

Tags: android, json

I want to send my data to server in the form of Json, I have written coding part which will send my data in the form of Json now I want to test this code. Now the problem is at present my server side code is not complete so how do I so it. I want to send three strings to the server side and I have used this link to convert the output in form of Json. [Android JSON HttpClient to send data to PHP server with HttpResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540786/android-json-httpclient-to-send-data-to-php-server-with-httpresponse)
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have written in this form 
 StringEntity s = new StringEntity(c.toString());
    s.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));

where c is JSONObject

Comment: I don't get it, JSONObject class is supposed to generate the JSON output correctly everytime you call toString(). Thats if you added the values. Like: **JSONObject c = new JSONObject(); c.put("string1", "prateek"); c.put("string2", "me"); c.put("string3", "you"); string finalJson = c.toString();**

Comment: when you print "j.toString()" ?

Comment: @WoLfulus JSONObject class is generating the JSON output correctly what i want is to check weather my rest of the code which I have taken from this link <Android JSON HttpClient to send data to PHP server with HttpResponse> is working or not so how to do it. and sorry for above comment it was my mistake, i have not putted any data in strings tht why it was showing only curl braces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply put Toast or System.out.println to check your output Json Format.

Comment: WOP programming on its purest form :)

Comment: I want to write my code in such a way that when my server side code is ready then I just have to replace the Url to my server Url. I have used link mentioned in the question for the reference