# How to get json object from android to php

Tags: php, android, http-post

i am trying to build a web service for my android app.
    But i am having problem to sending parametres to php.
    I am using these code blocks to Http-Post.

```
    public String requestJson(String method, JSONObject parameters) {
        try {
            int TIMEOUT_MILLISEC = 10000; 
            HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

            String tmpUrl = serviceUrl.trim() + (serviceUrl.trim().endsWith("/") ? method : "/" + method);

            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(tmpUrl);

            request.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json; charset=utf-8");

            if (parameters != null)
            {
                request.setEntity(new StringEntity(parameters.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8));
            }

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

            final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            final String jsonResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error in web request: " + statusCode);
                Log.w(TAG, jsonResponse);
                return null;
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, jsonResponse);
                return jsonResponse;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in fetching JSON due to -> " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }


    public String testFunction() {
        try {
            JSONObject param = new JSONObject();
            param.put("testID", 123);
            JsonCevabi = requestJson("test.php", param);

            if (JsonCevabi != null) {
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(JsonCevabi);
                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(jo.getString("d"));

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                List<SampleEntity> resultList = (List<SampleEntity>) new Gson().fromJson(ja.toString(), new TypeToken<List<SampleEntity>>() {
                }.getType());
                return JsonCevabi;
            }
            else
                return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And my php code like this;

```
<?php

$id = json_decode($_POST['testID']);


$json = "{d:[{sample1:'".$id."',sample2:'value12'}]}";
$response = $_GET["callback"] . $json;
echo $response;
?>
```

What i am trying to do is sending TestID parametre to php. And i am expenting to return me to this value.

But i am getting {d:[{sample1:'',sample2:'value12'}]}

What i want is {d:[{sample1:'123',sample2:'value12'}]}

What i am missing?

EDIT: i found similar question but did not help;
[Android JSON HttpClient to send data to PHP server with HttpResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540786/android-json-httpclient-to-send-data-to-php-server-with-httpresponse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @chandresh_cool said there is a problem with POST paramethers.
You should edit your StringEntity like this:
`new StringEntity("testID="+parameters.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8)`.

Then in your server the $id variable contains the decoded JSON, so you should do:

```
$id = json_decode($_POST['testID'], true);
$json = "{d:[{sample1:'".$id['testID']."',sample2:'value12'}]}";
```

Comment: i tried what you said. but no luck. i must doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like

```
$_POST['testID']
```

is a problem. Are you sending variable using post method surely?

Comment: i guess in the testFunction like this; 
JSONObject param = new JSONObject();
            param.put("testID", 123);

Answer (score 1):

Changing php code to following solved my problem.

```
<?php
$postdata = $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;
$data = json_decode($postdata);
$id = $data->testID;
$json = "{d:[{sample1:'".$id."',sample2:'value12'}]}";
$response = $_GET["callback"] . $json;
echo $response;
?>
```

http://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/the-simplest-way-to-post-parameters-between-android-and-php/

More detailed information can be found link above.

Comment: After some investigation I discovered that $_POST is used only when the content-type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`

Answer (score 1):

```
@Java Code to send data: 

StringEntity entity = new StringEntity("jsonRequest="+data.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);                
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity entityPost = response.getEntity();
result = EntityUtils.toString(entityPost);
return result;

@PHP code to receive data
$jsonRequest = json_decode($_REQUEST['jsonRequest'], true);

@check if the data is coming we can log the contents
date_default_timezone_set('EST');

ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "site.log");
error_log( "Hello, errors!".print_r($jsonRequest[id],1) );
```