# How can i send data from json?

Tags: android, json

I am building a android application where User log-in and enter basic information like Name, MailId and Birthday etc.

I want to parse all this data in my server I have create an API link that will save all user information in server database.

Now the problem is How can I send this user information to that API link.

here is my code -

```
 public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
Button btnRegister;
Button btnLinkToLogin;
EditText inputFullName;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputprofilepic;
TextView registerErrorMsg;

// JSON Response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_PROFILEPIC = "profilepic";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    //inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerName);
    //inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
    //inputprofilepic = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
    //btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    //btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);
    //registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);

    // Register Button Click event
    //btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           
        //public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = "hey";
            String email = "bbye";
            String profilepic = "thanks!";
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(name, email, profilepic);

            // check for login response
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    //registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        // user successfully registred
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), 
             json.getString(KEY_PROFILEPIC));                       
                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  
      DashboardActivity.class);
                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);
                        // Close Registration Screen
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        // Error in registration
                        //registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        //}
    //});

    // Link to Login Screen
    //btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        //public void onClick(View view) {

            // Close Registration View
            //finish();
        //}
    //});
}
}
```

Here is my json code -

```
 public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

And here is my userfunction code -

```
public class UserFunctions {

private JSONParser jsonParser;


private static String registerURL = "http://url";

private static String login_tag = "login";
private static String register_tag = "register";

// constructor
public UserFunctions(){
    jsonParser = new JSONParser();
}

/**
 * function make Login Request
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * */
public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String profilepic){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("profilepic", profilepic));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
    // return json
    // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
    return json;
}

/**
 * function make Login Request
 * @param name
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * */
public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String profilepic){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("profilepic", profilepic));

    // getting JSON Object
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
    // return json
    return json;
}

/**
 * Function get Login status
 * */
public boolean isUserLoggedIn(Context context){
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    int count = db.getRowCount();
    if(count > 0){
        // user logged in
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Function to logout user
 * Reset Database
 * */
public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    db.resetTables();
    return true;
}

   }
```

Comment: There are several code example available to send JSON data in server

Comment: I tried but there is an error! my application is foreclosed when is move to that code screen

Comment: Post Your code..Without code its impossible to solve

Comment: Oky just a sec I am editing my question and posting question in that!

Comment: Try this 
hmkcode.com/android-send-json-data-to-server/
And This

  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540786/android-json-httpclient-to-send-data-to-php-server-with-httpresponse

Comment: U want to send the data..but there is no single line of code which suggest you are trying to post the data...You are retreiving the data...!! Use HttpPost to post the data

Comment: Thanks @FunLove can you give an example! how I apply it my code

Comment: Or..wait..i give u sample

Comment: This will definitely help you http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Comment: Check the func..use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String postData() {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

  try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", myNameString));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", myPasswordString));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    InputStream parse = entity.getContent();

    return getStringFromInputStream(parse);

  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  }

    return "No Result !";
} 

 //convert InputStream to String
private  String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use url for sending data instead of json parse.

url1 = "http://"+ip+"/service.svc/AndPOMasterAdd?Auto=" + Auto + "&ClientId="+ ClientId +"&FinYr="+ FinYr +"&PDate="+ PDate +"&PTime="+ PTime +"&SuppID="+ SuppID +"&City="+ City +"&Prodid="+ Prodid +"&Design="+ Design +"&Qty="+ Qty +"&Rate="+ Rate +"&ImgPName="+ ImageName +"&CrBy="+ CRBY +"&CrDate="+ CRdate +"&Remark="+ Remark +"&ForBranch="+ ForBranch +"";